# How to get autocomplete search when select data in dropdown box

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete

Veiw code is below

```
<select name ="dept" id="dept">
   <option value="1">Software</option>
   <option value="2">Marketing</option>
</select>

<input name="section_name" id="section_name" type="text">
<input name="emp_id" id="emp_id" type="text">
```

Jquery Code is below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#section_name').keydown(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/search_con/section_name",
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {
        }
    });
  });   
$('#emp_id').keydown(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/search_con/emp_id",
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {
        }
    });
  });

});
```

Basically I want that when i will select Department dropdown, it will come autocomplete in section name, when in autocomplete section name will search section name and will select then here will come emp_id autocomplete and i will to do search Emp ID .

Other way i can say, It will be department's under section name and section name's under emp_id.

How can i solve successfully,  Please any help me.

Comment: Please clarify, I am not understanding it fully .. still a personal opinion

Comment: I mean that when i will select department then i will get section name in auto complete search and when i will select section name then i will get emp_id in auto complete search. I can say other way that I will get section name under department and i will get emp_id under section name. Am i clear to you Sedz.

Comment: Nope, that made me more confused 
When you select for example software do you want it to be in the section name input and then send to the server or what ?

Comment: Suppose, Software Department has 2 section For Example PHP and JAVA and In PHP Section has two employee Jone and Smith and Java has Jacky etc. Basically I want that when In dropdown box i will select software department then in autocomplete box will come section name (such as PHP and JAVA) and when in autocomplete search i will input/select PHP then in autocomplete will come (such as Jone and Smith). here Am i clear to you Sedz.

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two hidden fields or two variables as you like but I will do it with variables

When the user selects some department you should tell the server to search in that department so you will need to modify your BE code so you can achieve this

```
var current_department = ""; 

var current_lang = ""; 

//this will be called when ever the select changed 

$('#dept').change(function(){
current_department =  $(this).find(":selected").text();
});
```

In the department autocomplete you need to send the variable 
here it will send the department name you can set `val()`instead of `text()` it's up to you

Now the autocomplete should now about that so

```
$('#section_name').keydown(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/search_con/section_name/"+current_department,
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {
               //here you need to tell the next autocomplete what lang you selected e.g. PHP 
              current_lang = ui.item.value; //or .text it's up to you 
        }
    });
  });
```

So the next autocomplete should be like this

```
$('#emp_id').keydown(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/search_con/emp_id/"+current_lang,
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {
        }
    });
  });

});
```

Please remember to modify your ServerSide code 
I hope this can help you :)